# Why elements in a non-archimedian local field $F$ are of the form $\pi^n u$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, representation-theory, local-field

Let $F$ be a non-archimedian local field with valuation $\nu$. Then $\mathcal{O}=\{x\in F: \nu(x)\geq 0\}$ is the ring of integers of $F$. $\mathfrak{m}=\{x\in F: \nu(x)> 0\}$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}$. Let $\pi \in \mathcal{O}$ such that $\nu(\pi)=1$. It is said that every element $x$ in $F$ is of the form $\pi^n u$, where $n = \nu(x)$, $u$ is invertible in $F$. 
Why elements in $F$ are of the form $\pi^n u$?

In http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field, the ring $\mathcal{O}$ is given by $\{a \in F: \nu(a) \leq 1\}$. It is different from the definition in the first paragraph which is from the book Local filed by Serre. I am confused.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Checking on the definitions: Presumably $\nu(x)\in\Bbb{Z}$ for all $x\in F$ in your setting. So if $\nu(x)=k$, then $\nu(x\pi^{-k})=0$. So writing $u=x\pi^{-k}$, then $x=\pi^k u$, and $\nu(u)=0$, so $u$ is invertible in $\cal O$.

Comment: Also there are two conventions in denoting a valuation. Often
$$|a|=q^{\nu(a)},$$ where $q$ is a real number in the interval $(0,1)$ (in the $p$-adic case $q=1/p$). Then $|a|\le1$ iff $\nu(a)\ge0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the confusion: The $p$-adic **value** $|x|_p$ is obtained from the $p$-adic **valuation** $\nu_p(x)$ per $|x|_p = p^{-\nu_p(x)}$ (and $|0|_p=0$ to avoid the infinity occuring in $\nu_p(0)=\infty$). So we have $\nu_p(x)\ge 0\iff |x|_p\le 1$.

Since $\nu(x)\in\mathbb N_0$ for all $x\in \mathcal O$, the number $u:=\frac{x}{\pi^{\nu(x)}}\in F$ has the property $\nu(u)=0$.
Since $\mathcal O\setminus\mathfrak m=\mathcal O^\times$ this precisely says that $u$ is a unit.